# How do you set up the initial directory for a FileDialog to be in sharepoint and allow you to select multiple items in VBA?

Tags: vba, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, filedialog

What I am trying to do is open file dialog in a network path. I have figured out how to open it in the correct location, but it sets itself up as a website.

Here is the code:

```
Set files = Application.FileDialog(3) '3 is the File Picker type
    files.InitialFileName = "https://website.com/pathing/Document/"
    'files.InitialFileName = "\\website.com@SSL\pathing\Document\"
    files.AllowMultiSelect = True
    files.Show
```

Both lines that set the initial file name act exactly the same.

When I run the code I am unable to select more than one file. [Unwanted Behavior](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ngiB.jpg)

However, when I manually type in the pathing \\website.com@SSL\pathing\Document\ the File Dialog behaves as I want it to, allowing me to select multiple files. [Desired Behavior](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cnSYg.jpg)

Is there a way for me to get directly to the intended behavior without having to manually enter it into the explorer bar?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to access this directly, you need to tell the explorer that its dealing with webDav, which in fact SharePoint does if you open a library in an explorer view.

So the path to your library is `https://website.com/pathing/Document/`

So the UNC path looks like this:

`\\website.com\davWWWroot\pathing\document\`

You can however get the correct path all by yourself if you follow these steps:

1. Open the path in a browser
2. Switch to explorer view
3. Copy the address in the explorer
4. Map a network drive with the copied address.
5. The network drive has the desired UNC path for you.

Comment: The problem isn't being able to get to the right location. (I am in fact getting to the desired location). But when I open up the location through vba, it defaults to the view seen in the first link I posted and it does not allow me to select more than one file at a time.

However, if I click directly on the address line in the file explorer and type in the path "\\website.com\pathing\document\", it behaves as desired and lets me select multiple files.

Comment: Have you used davWWWroot in your path?

Comment: Yes, and it still behaves the same way.

Comment: @Andrew Meagher Did you ever solve the problem? I have the same issue with every application that uses the FileDialog.